# How to replace ',' without replacing it in unit in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to replace "," to @ in following strings, but without changing it in unit (10,000) format.

1. `x,y,z` to `x@y@z`
2. `x1,y1,z1` to `x1@y1@z1`
3. `x1,y1 10,000,z1` to `x1@y1 10,000@z1`

I used `s/(\D),/\1@/g`, but it won't work for 2 and 3. How to recognize the exclusion pattern is digit on both sides? Can someone help? thanks so much

Comment: try s/(,\D)|(\D,)/\1@/g

Comment: Is it possible to see `x1,y1,10,000`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a regex which says to match a comma that does not have a number to its left or right.

```
s/(?<!\d),|,(?!\d)/@/g
```

The negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!\d)` allows matches such as `x,`, since x is not a number. Using a negated expression allows this to also match beginning of line, e.g. `,x`. The negative lookahead assertion `(?!\d)` allows matches against commas that are not followed by numbers. Neither of these expressions will match a comma surrounded by numbers.

Comment: Yes, this indeed covers that either side is digit. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following alternative:

```
s/,(?<!\d)(?!\d)/\@/g;
```

**sample script**

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my @array = ( 'x,y,z', 'x1,y1,z1', 'x1,y1 10,000,z1');

for my $string (@array) {
    $string =~ s/,(?<!\d)(?!\d)/\@/g;
    print "$string\n";
}
#OUTPUT
#x@y@z
#x1@y1@z1
#x1@y1 10,000@z1
```

Comment: No, it does not work, the negative lookbehind is in the wrong place. So it fails for `x,1`.